# Dynamics CRM online, throwing System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to call a Web API endpoint(https) using client certificate in Dynamics CRM plugin on Sandbox environment and I am getting the following error message.

```
Unhandled Exception: 
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): MyTestPlugin.PatchOnRevise: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>9eb9f246-31da-42d4-a8ad-a93b16c783d7</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220956</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): MyTestPlugin.PatchOnRevise: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2018-07-08T22:01:17.969528Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>
```

This is the code wherein I am attaching the certificate to WebClient.

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri _address)
        {
            X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(_bytes);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(_address);
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate2);
            return request;
        }
```

I have tried to disable Sandbox, but no luck. Is there anything else I need to do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable sandbox in an online environment.

I suspect the issue is related to this, I'm not sure if certificate based security is supported.

[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)

> **Web access**
>
> Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
>   network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides
>   support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news
>   feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions
>   apply to this sandbox capability.
>
> - Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
> - Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
> - IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
> - **Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended**. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or
>     saving those credentials.